# OpenCL kernel work-group size restriction

Tags: opencl

So I keep running into strange errors when I call my kernels; the stated max kernel work-group size is one, while the work group size of my device (my Macbook) is decidedly higher than that. What possible causes could there be for the kernels restricting the code to a single work group? Here's one of my kernels:

```
__kernel
void termination_kernel(const    int    Elements,
                    __global float* c_I,
                    __global float* c_Ihat,
                    __global float* c_rI,
                    __local  float* s_a)
{
  const int bdim = 128;
  int n = get_global_id(0);
  const int tx = get_local_id(0); // thread index in thread-block (0-indexed)
  const int bx = get_group_id(0);  // block index (0-indexed)
  const int gx = get_num_groups(0);

  // is thread in range for the addition
  float d = 0.f;
  while(n < Elements){
    d += pow(c_I[n] - c_Ihat[n], 2);
    n += gx * bdim;
  }

  // assume bx power of 2 
  int alive = bdim / 2;
  s_a[tx] = d;
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  while(alive > 1){
    if(tx < alive)
      s_a[tx] += s_a[tx + alive];
    alive /= 2;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  }

  if(tx == 0)
    c_rI[bx] = s_a[0] + s_a[1]; 
}
```

and the error returned is

```
OpenCL Error (via pfn_notify): [CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE] : OpenCL Error : clEnqueueNDRangeKernel     
failed: total work group size (128) is greater than the device can support (1)
OpenCL Error: 'clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel_N, dim, NULL, global_N, local_N, 0, NULL, NULL)'
```

I know it says the restriction is on the device, but debugging shows that

```
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE = 1024
```

and

```
CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE = 1
```

The kernel construction is called by

```
  char *KernelSource_T = readSource("Includes/termination_kernel.cl"); 
  cl_program program_T = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &KernelSource_T, NULL, &err);
  clBuildProgram(program_T, 1, &device, flags, NULL, NULL);
  cl_kernel kernel_T = clCreateKernel(program_T, "termination_kernel", &err);
```

I'd include the calling function, but I'm not sure if it's relevant; my intuition is that it's something in the kernel code that's forcing the restriction. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You should show the rest of the source code - the Enqueue and SetArgs commands.

Comment: What hardware specifically are you running the code on?

Answer (score 3):

Apple OpenCL doesn't support work-groups larger than [1, 1, 1] on the CPU. I have no idea why, but that's how it's been at least up to OSX 10.9.2. Larger work-groups are fine on the GPU, though.

Comment: This is an OSX thing though. On Linux, larger work group sizes are fine when running on the CPU. On linux, the same cl code is 3.5 times faster for me as well. Is OSX OpenCL simply broken for cpu?

Answer (score 1):

CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE tells you how large the maximum work group size can be for this particular kernel. OpenCL's runtime determines that by inspecting the kernel code. CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE will be a number less or equal to CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the amount of local memory avilable is less for that work group size . Please can you show the arguments? . You can try by reducing the work group size , start with 2,4,8,16,32,64,128 so on make sure its power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Time has passed since the [answer of Tomi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287001/4375377) and it seems that Apple has become slightly more flexible on this aspect. On my OS X 10.12.3 (still OpenCL 1.2), it is possible to use up to `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` in the first dimension.

According to the specification, it is also possible to get the maximum number of work-groups for each dimension through `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` according to the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)